# multiprocessing.pool in python for speeding column wise linear regression in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a large pandas dataframe. I want to fit a simple linear regression fit for every column of df1 against the first df1 column. The goal is to produce a new dataframe where each row has the results of the linear regression fit for each column. I can do this in a for loop using the code below. However, this is very slow and I want to speed it up.

```
def lin_reg(col_x, df1_col_iterator):
    lm = stats.linregress(df1_col_iterator, col_y)
    slope, intercept, r, p, se_slope, se_intercept = lm.slope, lm.intercept, lm.rvalue, lm.pvalue, lm.stderr, lm.intercept_stderr
    new_row = [df1_col_iterator.name, slope, intercept, r, p, se_slope, se_intercept]
    return new_row

coef_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col", "slope", "intercept", "rvalue","pvalue","slope_stderr", "intercept_stderr"])

for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns[1:]): #first col is col_y
            new_row = lin_reg(df1[col], df1[col_y])
            coef_df.loc[i] = new_row
```

I have tried to use multiprocessing to speed this up as I am only using <10% CPU capacity but I have struggled to get it to work. I have attempted to use the starmap function, as per below:

```
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        for i, col in df.columns[1:]:
            args = [df[col], df[col_y]]
            new_row = pool.starmap(lin_reg, args)
            coef_df.loc[i] = new_row
        pool.close()
```

When running I get the below message;

```
RuntimeError:


    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

I suspect I have not understood the input to starmap, but I have looked at a few tutorials and am still struggling. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: In windows, multiprocessing creates a new python instance and reimports your module. If the pool execution code runs on import, you have an infinite loop. The new process hits the pool creation code, which creates a new process, which hits the pool creation code, etc... Instead, do what the error says. Make sure that the executable code at module level is underneath `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: Its hard to get better performance with multiprocessing and pandas. That entire column needs to be copied to the subprocess and result copied back. You may have luck using a thread pool instead. pandas may release the GIL, giving you parallelism.